# Expression index on a citext column ignored, why?

Tags: postgresql, index, citext

Running on RDS with about 32M rows.

```
PostgreSQL 11.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit
```

Also testing locally on macOS with about 8M rows.

```
PostgreSQL 11.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42), 64-bit
```

I've got a column named `old_value` that's of type citext. I asked about this already, but posted *way* to many of my discovery steps along the way. Here's a boiled down version that I'm hoping gets to the point.

## Background

I've got a field change log table named record_changes_log_detail with 32M rows and growing that includes a citext field named old_value.

The data is *very* skeweed. Most values are less than a dozen characters, some are more than 5,000.

Postgres chokes on large values with an error about B-tree entries being limited to 2172 characters. So I believe that for a B-tree, I need to substring the source value.

My users primary interest is in an = search, a starts-with search, and, sometimes, a contains-this-substring search. So = string% and %string%

## Goals

Create an index that supports those searches that the planner uses.

## Tried and failed

A straight B-tree fails to build, in some cases, because of long values.

An expression B-tree like this builds, but is not used

```
CREATE INDEX record_changes_log_detail_old_value_ix_btree
    ON  record_changes_log_detail 
    USING btree (substring(old_value,1,1024));
```

Adding text_pattern_opts does not help.

```
CREATE INDEX record_changes_log_detail_old_value_ix_btree
    ON  record_changes_log_detail 
    USING btree (substring(old_value,1,1024) text_pattern_opts);
```

## Tried and works partially

A hash index works, but only for equality. (Like it says on the tin.)

This is the closest I've gotten to success:

```
CREATE INDEX record_changes_log_detail_old_value_ix_btree
    ON record_changes_log_detail 
    USING btree (old_value citext_pattern_ops);
```

This works for quality, but not for LIKE. The release notes for PG 11 say it should work for LIKE:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html

By "work" I mean "the index is used."

I was unable to substring succesfully with this approach.

What do people do in this situation with citext fields?

Comment: For reference, I went back to an excellent series of Postgres indexes: http://habr.com/en/company/postgrespro/blog/442776/

The hashing function is exposed: select hashtext('Hello world!') -- -1587637769.

Not sure what's actually stored in the index nodes...the hashing function is likely just helping get a bucket number? I'll have to dig a bit more...

Comment: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/backend/access/hash

If I read the read me for the source correctly (!), then the hashing function gets you to a bucket (by some steps), the bucket page includes the OID of the source row, and does *not* include the source value. That all sounds good. It also sounds like pages are never returned unless you REINDEX so, well, hmm. I'd rather use a B-tree in my case...but it just won't kick in :(

Comment: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/access/hash/hashfunc.c

Sounds like the hash function result is a 32-bit value.

Comment: For the record, I did a VACUUM ANALYZE on the table and the B-tree index is still ignored in a LIKE 'string%' search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unusual to index such a long column entirely.

Three ideas:

1. Modify the query like this:

   ```
   WHERE substring(old_value, 1, 100) LIKE substring(pattern, 1, 100)
     AND old_value LIKE pattern
   ```

   (`pattern` here would be the pattern string, something like `'string%'`.)

   Then a b-tree index on `substring(old_value, 1, 100)` can be used (if the pattern doesn't start with a wildcard character of course).
2. Depending on the exact requirements (are you searching complete words or word prefixes in a natural language text or not), [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) may be a good solution.
3. Another option are of course *trigram indexes*:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON record_changes_log_detail USING gin (old_value gin_trgm_ops);
   ```

   This requires the `pg_trgm` extension to be installed.

   Such an index will work also for search patterns that start with a wildcard. For good performance, enforce a minimum length on the search string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, it's typically pointless to index such a large field. I'm used to doing so in another environment (priors === bad assumptions). In fact, all but a very few values are short or not long. Being a bit thick here, but what is pattern in your example above? And, yes, I've got to take another look at FTS and n-grams.There are lots of code fragments and error dumps in our text generally, so the last time I looked at stem-based FTS in Postgres it didn't help. N-grams are the greatest, so I'd be happy to have an excuse to use them in Postgres. Time to look again!

Comment: I have added some explanations to the answer and added something about trigram indexes.

Comment: Tri-grams rule! I love n-grams, and the Postgres implementation seems great. For those following along at home, the secret is to cast the value to ::text in your search, like this: select * from record_changes_log_detail 
where old_value::text LIKE '%Gold Kerrison Neuro%'; If you've built an index like Laurenz' specified, you can confirm with explain analyze that it's used. Fantastic!

Answer (score 3):

Please edit your question, rather than posting answers to it that don't answer it.

If you create an index on the expression `substring(old_value,1,1024)`, then that index can only get used if you query involves `substring(old_value,1,1024)`.

While it is theoretically possible to prove that `old_value='foo'` implies that `substring(old_value,1,1024)='foo'` (and thus the contrapositive to that) if you have enough insight into the internals of substring, **PostgreSQL makes no attempt to prove that**.  You need to write the query in a way that no such proof is needed.

Comment: Yeah, my question(s) got out of control. I suck at writing short. I've boiled everything down into a summary instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm back to close this question out. Following up on a suggestion from Laurenz Albe, I gave the Postgres tri-gram implementation a try. They rule!

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS record_changes_log_detail_old_value_ix_tgrm;
CREATE INDEX record_changes_log_detail_old_value_ix_tgrm
    ON record_changes_log_detail 
    USING gin (old_value gin_trgm_ops);
```

The secret here when you're using citext is to cast your value to ::text, like so:

```
select * from record_changes_log_detail 
where old_value::text LIKE '%Gold Kerrison Neuro%';
```

Running that with explain analyze confirms that the index is used. I noticed that I have to use LIKE for an = search, but that's okay.

Comment: I've faced simlar problems and tried this solution. I find that it makes to query case senstive again. So actually removes the point of it been a citext field.